# Selecting elements without selectors, using element ID only

Tags: javascript, dom

I've always had to use a selector to get elements in the DOM so I could retrieve the data that I need. eg:

```
var test1 = document.getElementById('testElement').value; // or
var test2 = document.querySelector('#testElement').value; // or
var test3 = $('#testElement').val(); // etc...
```

Recently, I noticed that I no longer need to do that. Instead, simply using the element's id seems to be sufficient. It seems to be used as a reference to the element. The code below works for me in Chrome, Firefox and even IE9.

```
var test4 = testElement.value;
```

I've been trying to find some more information on this but wherever I look, everyone says that selectors need to be used.
So either my colleagues and I completely missed this somehow, or not many people know about this. Or, I suppose, I'm horrible at searching for information.

**Basically, I'm looking for more information on this.**

So please point me in the right direction so I can investigate further and make sure this functionality is here to stay and can be used consistently.

Comment: @canon Though I absolutely hate duplicates, I've created another one. Apologies, I will research further next time. Thanks for the link though. It explained the situation well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser feature, which is **not** according to the specification. This means that for your code to work on most browsers, it should be using some selector. Also, `testElement` may not work if it already is a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser the element id *may be* in the global scope. That is a nice feature and all but I would not depend on this for your applications. If you want to be thorough I suggest using `getElementById()` or a selector with jQuery.